# How to store a javascript code or other language code and use that code website using url

Tags: javascript, blogs, blogger

like this:

```
style="text/javascript" 
src="http://helplogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/recent-posts-with-titles-only.js"
```

Please help me>.......

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your trying to do, the same as you appen any JS library

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://helplogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/recent-posts-with-titles-only.js">`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<script>` html's tag for that.

use:

```
 <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

whenever the script is relative to your webpage

and use:

```
 <script src="http://www.example.com/example.js"></script>
```

whenever the script is external to your webpage.

This kind of things are well documented on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) webpage.

i.e. :

You could see a complet definition of how `<script>` tag works [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp).